# Salesforce Files Connect and Azure: "Error: Invalid URL"

Tags: files, sharepoint, office-365, azure

As of 2018-02-19, Salesforce's [official "preferred" instructions to set up Files Connect with Azure/SharePoint](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_files_connect_sp_online_auth.htm&type=5) include the following:

> - **Authorize Endpoint URL:** Enter the URL as follows: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?prompt=consent&​resource=https%3A%2F%2FYOUR_TENANT.sharepoint.com%2F`

Trying to follow these instructions will lead to an **"Error: Invalid URL"** error that does not let me save the authentication provider.

If we take a look at the [official instructions on how to set up any generic authenticator](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sso_provider_sfdc.htm&type=5), they state (step 8a) that:

> For the Authorize Endpoint URL ... the path must end in `/services/oauth2/authorize`.

Following this second set of instructions, if we drop the `prompt` and `resource` parameters from the URL and leave it as `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize`, saving the authorization provider goes through, but it does not follow Salesforce's instructions for this specific case.

If I drop the parameters and try to continue with the instructions and [set up an external data source](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_files_connect_sp_online_xds.htm&type=5), testing the settings results in the following error:

> We can’t log you in because of the following error. For more information, contact your Salesforce administrator.
>
> No_Oauth_Token: invalid_resource AADSTS50001: Resource identifier is not provided.Trace ID: 6bee5681-d31b-4461-8675-fa3d7af22e00Correlation ID: c16e9be3-a260-4ab8-8986-32c4be5d89a3Timestamp: 2018-02-19 17:40:38Z

What am I doing wrong? What is the best way out of this error that allows me to finish setting up Files Connect with Azure/Office 365?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error came from the fact that I was copying and pasting either from the PDF or the website and that was adding a hidden carriage return to the URL.

That field actually takes parameters in the URL address without an issue.